# Is there a function that updates var value in django views.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

Good day, I am very new to django and programming in general. Is there a function that updates variable values based on user input?

I would like to write a function that displays output to html using HttpResponse and waits for user input...

on my views.py, I have the following:

```
def getResponse(request):
    userMessage = request.GET.get('userMessage');
    return HttpResponse("Good to see you. May I know your name?")
    name=input(userMessage)
    return HttpResponse("Good to know you", name,". I can tell you your age if you tell me which year you were born")
    year=input(userMessage)
    age = ((datetime.date.today().year) - year)
    return HttpResponse("You are", age "old")
```

My Html is looking like this:

```
    <div id="userInput">
    <form id="user_Input"   method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="userMessage" id="textInput" placeholder="Type your 
         message...">
      <input type="submit" id="buttonInput"  name="" value="Send">
     </form>
   </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function getUserResponse(){

var userText =$('#textInput').val();
var userHTML = "<p class='userText'>User: <span>"+userText+"</span></p>";
$('#textInput').val("");

$('#pal').append(userHTML);

$.get('/qpal/getResponse',{userMessage:userText}).done(function(data){
  var returnedMessage = "<p class='botText'> Pal: <span>"+ data +"</span></p>";
    $('#pal').append(returnedMessage);
})

}

$('#buttonInput').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  getUserResponse();
})


</script>
```

The html works, however it is only displaying the first HttpResponse value everytime like shown in the picture[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TJJx.png).

In pure python environment the code will work perfectly using only print and input and I am trying to make it work the same on the web (html) using django

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Search for "django channels chat tutorial". I see you want to make some sort of a chat.

Comment: Why don't you handle all the code with Python?

Comment: @EnePaul, thank you very much. I will try those tutorials and try and make another practice project on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using too many return without condition which is wrong and due this your function always return the first message.

you should store or update the message variable based on the user input such as you can use another variable on your HTML named as `Qnum` question number and based on that show next next message:-

```
def getResponse(request, QNum):
    message = "Hi"
    if QNum == 1:
       userMessage = request.GET.get('userMessage');
       message = "Good to see you. May I know your name?"
    elif QNum == 2:
        message = "Good to know you, {}. I can tell you your age if you tell me which year you were born".format(input(userMessage))
    elif QNum == 3: 
        year=input(userMessage)
        age = ((datetime.date.today().year) - year)
        message = "You are, {} old".format(age)
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I added a javascript that counts the number of times the button is clicked and took that value to views to make a variable for QNum. It did not work at first but I realized that an integer was involved for the conditions to be met. I went to convert QNum into an integer and then it started working well. I appreciate your idea. Thank you

Comment: thank you! Happy to help you!